# genfromtxt issues of import a txt file

Tags: linux, numpy, genfromtxt

I have a data file with top names like:

```
    position        avgx        avgy        avgz        stdx        stdy        stdt        avgG    nemixrms    nemiyrms    nemirrms        rmax
 2.800e+00 -4.997e-05 -1.373e-04  2.800e+00  2.812e-03  2.819e-03  4.641e-10  1.684e+00  7.433e-06  7.377e-06  7.404e-06  1.224e-02
 2.750e+00 -3.592e-05 -1.040e-04  2.750e+00  2.110e-03  2.129e-03  4.634e-10  1.684e+00  6.412e-06  6.361e-06  6.386e-06  9.652e-03
 2.700e+00 -2.209e-05 -7.128e-05  2.700e+00  1.457e-03  1.485e-03  4.627e-10  1.684e+00  5.346e-06  5.338e-06  5.342e-06  7.083e-03
 2.650e+00 -8.730e-06 -4.000e-05  2.650e+00  8.753e-04  9.082e-04  4.620e-10  1.684e+00  4.352e-06  4.439e-06  4.395e-06  4.591e-03
 2.600e+00  4.074e-06 -1.208e-05  2.600e+00  4.273e-04  4.515e-04  4.613e-10  1.683e+00  3.728e-06  3.968e-06  3.846e-06  3.210e-03
 2.590e+00  6.587e-06 -7.411e-06  2.590e+00  3.688e-04  3.880e-04  4.612e-10  1.683e+00  3.675e-06  3.941e-06  3.805e-06  3.183e-03
 2.550e+00  1.580e-05  5.137e-06  2.550e+00  3.594e-04  3.587e-04  4.606e-10  1.683e+00  3.741e-06  4.020e-06  3.878e-06  3.100e-03
 2.500e+00  2.600e-05  1.130e-05  2.500e+00  7.696e-04  7.677e-04  4.600e-10  1.684e+00  4.343e-06  4.436e-06  4.389e-06  3.939e-03
 2.450e+00  3.586e-05  1.554e-05  2.450e+00  1.358e-03  1.353e-03  4.593e-10  1.684e+00  4.701e-06  4.760e-06  4.730e-06  5.477e-03
 2.400e+00  4.561e-05  1.929e-05  2.400e+00  2.027e-03  2.018e-03  4.587e-10  1.684e+00  4.907e-06  4.993e-06  4.874e-06  7.949e-03
 2.350e+00  5.562e-05  2.210e-05  2.350e+00  2.746e-03  2.731e-03  4.580e-10  1.684e+00  8.541e-06  8.710e-06  4.954e-06  1.051e-02
 2.250e+00  7.616e-05 -3.145e-06  2.250e+00  4.084e-03  4.011e-03  4.567e-10  1.684e+00  1.881e-04  1.882e-04  5.092e-06  1.489e-02
 2.200e+00  6.767e-05 -2.592e-05  2.200e+00  4.086e-03  4.011e-03  4.561e-10  1.684e+00  8.753e-05  8.755e-05  5.263e-06  1.456e-02
 2.150e+00  5.840e-05 -2.875e-05  2.150e+00  3.881e-03  3.818e-03  4.555e-10  1.684e+00  1.502e-05  1.496e-05  5.555e-06  1.345e-02
 2.050e+00  4.430e-05 -2.326e-05  2.050e+00  3.528e-03  3.479e-03  4.543e-10  1.684e+00  6.266e-06  6.305e-06  6.283e-06  1.120e-02
 2.000e+00  3.752e-05 -1.994e-05  2.000e+00  3.393e-03  3.350e-03  4.537e-10  1.684e+00  6.618e-06  6.664e-06  6.639e-06  1.009e-02
 1.950e+00  3.073e-05 -1.661e-05  1.950e+00  3.287e-03  3.249e-03  4.531e-10  1.684e+00  6.944e-06  6.988e-06  6.964e-06  9.006e-03
 1.900e+00  2.391e-05 -1.328e-05  1.900e+00  3.211e-03  3.180e-03  4.526e-10  1.684e+00  7.227e-06  7.265e-06  7.243e-06  7.935e-03
```

I am using numpy.genfromtxt to import this data file as

```
screendata=genfromtxt('../screen.txt',delimiter=',',names=True,dtype=None)
```

If I print screendata, it shows me:

```
[ (b'2.800e+00 -4.997e-05 -1.373e-04  2.800e+00  2.812e-03  2.819e-03  4.641e-10  1.684e+00  7.433e-06  7.377e-06  7.404e-06  1.224e-02',)
 (b'2.750e+00 -3.592e-05 -1.040e-04  2.750e+00  2.110e-03  2.129e-03  4.634e-10  1.684e+00  6.412e-06  6.361e-06  6.386e-06  9.652e-03',)
 (b'2.700e+00 -2.209e-05 -7.128e-05  2.700e+00  1.457e-03  1.485e-03  4.627e-10  1.684e+00  5.346e-06  5.338e-06  5.342e-06  7.083e-03',)
 (b'2.650e+00 -8.730e-06 -4.000e-05  2.650e+00  8.753e-04  9.082e-04  4.620e-10  1.684e+00  4.352e-06  4.439e-06  4.395e-06  4.591e-03',)
 (b'2.600e+00  4.074e-06 -1.208e-05  2.600e+00  4.273e-04  4.515e-04  4.613e-10  1.683e+00  3.728e-06  3.968e-06  3.846e-06  3.210e-03',)
 (b'2.590e+00  6.587e-06 -7.411e-06  2.590e+00  3.688e-04  3.880e-04  4.612e-10  1.683e+00  3.675e-06  3.941e-06  3.805e-06  3.183e-03',)
 (b'2.550e+00  1.580e-05  5.137e-06  2.550e+00  3.594e-04  3.587e-04  4.606e-10  1.683e+00  3.741e-06  4.020e-06  3.878e-06  3.100e-03',)
 (b'2.500e+00  2.600e-05  1.130e-05  2.500e+00  7.696e-04  7.677e-04  4.600e-10  1.684e+00  4.343e-06  4.436e-06  4.389e-06  3.939e-03',)
```

I try to get the colume data like:

```
screendata['position']
```

It shows error message

```
      print(screendata['position'])
ValueError: field named position not found
```

Then, I tried

```
print(screendata.dtype.names)

('position________avgx________avgy________avgz________stdx________stdy________stdt________avgG____nemixrms____nemiyrms____nemirrms________rmax',)
```

How could I import this kind of data into python, that I could manipulate in colume mode?
Thanks!

Comment: Why is your delimiter a comma when your data is delimited by blank spaces?

Comment: I tried delimiter by ' ' but shows ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 21 columns instead of 77)
    Line #3 (got 21 columns instead of 77)
    Line #4 (got 21 columns instead of 77)
    Line #5 (got 21 columns instead of 77)

Comment: Just don't add "delimiter=...'.

Comment: Thanks very much